# Show that the sets $S = \{s \in [0,1]: sb + (1-s)a \in A\}$ and $T = \{t \in [0,1]: tb + (1-t)a \in B\}$ are open

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

Book: Functions of Complex Variables
Chapter: 2 Topology in $\mathbb{C}$
Section 2.2: Exercise 2: Show that the sets $S$ and $T$ from Theorem 2.3 are open.

Theorem 2.3: Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, then the set $G$ is connected if and only if for any two points $a,b$ in $G$ the polygon that connects a and b lies entirely inside G. (path connected).

What I have so far:

$\\ \\ \textbf{Proof:} \\ \\$

By definition,

$S = \{s \in [0,1]: sb + (1-s)a \in A\}$,
$T = \{t \in [0,1]: tb + (1-t)a \in B\}$

We also have that A,B are open/closed subsets of G such that:

$S\cup T = [0,1], S\cap T = \emptyset, G = A\cup B, A\cap B = \emptyset$

Hence, one part of the segment $[a,b]$ lies in $A$, and the other part lies in $B$. Also we know that $0 \in S$, and $1 \in T$. Hence, we can write the sets 
$S$ and $T$ as

$S = [0,c), T = (c,1], \mbox{ and } S\cup T = [0,1], S \cap T = \emptyset.$

Now, $\forall s \in S$ and $\forall t \in T$, we have that
$B^{[0,1]}(s,c - s) \subseteq S \mbox{ and } B^{[0,1]}(t,t - c) \subseteq T$
Hence, $S$ and $T$ are open.

Am I right?

Comment: Open in $[0,1]$ under the subspace topology? What are $A$ and $B$ subsets of?

Comment: I edit the question. This problems arise in the proof of Theorem 2.3 of Conway's book. We assume that for any two points a,b in G the polygon lies entirely inside G, but G is not connected and we want to get a contradiction. Since G is not connected, there exists two subsets of G such that their union is G, they are disjoints, and open and closed at the same time and this contradicts the connectedness of [0,1] but we only must show that S,T are open. The book does not explain well where those sets S,T must be open, but I am assuming is on [0,1].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $c:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $c(t)=tb+(1-t)a$. This is clearly continuous, and $S=c^{-1}(A)$, $T=c^{-1}(B)$. Since $A,B$ are open, $S$ and $T$ are also open.

Comment: I added that G must be open. Thanks. Also I posted all the information related to the problem (the book and so on) and in my reply to @pjs36 I explain a little bit more.